# Vertical average of array of array

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, matrix

I have the following input (3xn matrix)

```
const centers: [number, number, number][] = [[1, 2, 3], [1.2, 2,4, 3,3], [0.9, 2.4, 2.9], [1.1, 2,7, 3,4]];
```

The numbers in an object represent x, y,z coords. I need to find their average point. Could you please help me with algorithm. How can I get rid of manually setting the index to 1,2,3. Thanks in advance.

I have this as follows:

```
 const length = centers.length;
  return [
    centers.map((value) => value[0]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / length,
    centers.map((value) => value[1]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / length,
    centers.map((value) => value[2]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / length
  ];
```

EDIT:
With your very helpful comments, the result is:

```
centers[0].map((_, index) => centers.map(row => row[index])).map(value => value.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / centers.length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `.map` on the first row, then use the index:

```
 centers[0].map((_, index) => 
   centers.map(row => row[index]) /*...*/
 )
```